# Get a list of all open windows from the command line

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, is it possible to obtain a list of all open desktop windows from the command line? I know that it's possible to obtain a [list of all running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows) from the command line, but I want to know if it's possible to obtain a list of open windows as well.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191206/how-to-get-list-of-running-applications-using-powershell-or-vbscript) appears similar, but I'm not sure if it does exactly the same thing. Is obtaining a list of all running Windows applications equivalent to obtaining a list of all open windows?

Comment: Here's one possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456091/get-a-list-of-all-open-windows-using-autoit

Comment: there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25771386/get-all-windows-of-a-process-in-powershe

Answer (score 9):

The "/v" option lists the window names in the last column.  As in "tasklist /v".  You can also pipe it into another application or find to do filtering.

Comment: tasklist /v is super slow

Comment: And `tasklist /v` fails to query many titles, for instance when you have a lot of chrome tabs open, it only lists the title of the chrome tab that is in front.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq <Title of window*>"
```

For example:

```
tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Notepad*"
```

Comment: Now I wonder if it would be feasible to obtain the list of open windows without knowing the title of each window in advance.

Comment: There should be a eq or ne condition in there as well:

tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Notepad*"

Comment: @Almund - You should have edited the answer to fix that. I've taken care of it.

Comment: I don't need active processes, I need active windows. One process can open few windows. Also this command doesn't work even if only one window is created.

Answer (score 3):

WinLister from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net) list all windows active on a machine as well as associated information (title, path, handle, class, position, process ID, thread ID, etc.). It has a GUI interface rather than command-line.

Comment: better then is GUIPropView from nirsoft.

Answer (score 2):

if you just use the following command, it will list all active processes

> tasklist

Or filtering by session name would restrict a bit more to get processes started by console:

> tasklist /FI "SESSIONNAME eq Console"

Comment: I don't need active processes, I need active windows. One process can open few windows.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell. The command is: Get-Process

You can try this:

```
##Method 1: (Gives you all the processes)
Get-Process

## Method 2: Detailed Info On a specific named Process
$ProcessTerm="chrome"
#Run This:
$FindProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -like "*$processterm*"}
Get-Process -ID $FindProcess.ID | Select-Object *

# FindProcess.ID will give you the ID of the above process

#Method 3: (if you know the process ID)
$ProcessID = "9068"
$FindProcess = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.id -eq "$ProcessID"}
Get-Process -ID $FindProcess.Id | Select-Object *
```

Comment: The question was about windows and not about processes.