# How to get running program list[not all processes] from cmd?

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-prompt

I don't need list of all processes. I just want the opened programs.

I have used TASKLIST and WMIC commands. But both of them give the all processes.

Comment: What's the difference between an "opened program" and a process?

Comment: I think both are same. But I don't need background processes. If I have opened Notepad and Firefox, I want the list with only notepad and Firefox. I think not the opened programs. It should be corrected as user applications.

Comment: Yes they are the same, which is the point. How are you going to be able to tell the difference? That's the problem. Also, why do you need to know? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191206/how-to-get-list-of-running-applications-using-powershell-or-vbscript

Answer (score 1):

This removes the list of services:

```
tasklist /v|find /v /i " services "
```

Comment: But the result still comes with background applications.

Comment: You got the running program list though.  All in the system tray etc.

Comment: yeah you're right...